# Can not move SQL Primary File

Tags: filesystems, sql-server-2005, file-permissions

In the process of moving/upgrading old SQL server 2005, I need to move some sharepoint PWA datafiles.

After detaching the database from the files, I am trying to copy/move the DB files from their old location, to a new one. Getting the following error:

[image]

- I tried both as Domain Administrator and Local Computer administrator
- I tried running Explorer and CMD as Administrator
- I tried to copy to a temporary folder on the local computer - to prevent network/other authentication issues.
- Takeown is not working either

[image: Before]

The files are marked somehow as SQL Primary Database files

I can't copy the files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Permissions get changed on physical files when the database is detached.  If you detached the database using a Windows login they get set so only the account used to detach has access (no others, not even the local administrators group).  If you used a SQL login to detach then the SQL Server service account will be the only one with access.  You'll need to use that account to work with the files.

Comment: AWSOME! The files got my domain user. Thanks - fixed

Comment: Great!  Glad it's working for you now!